# Python get JSON object by index

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that looks something like this:

```
{ data:
      { 123:

      { 212:

      { 343:
```

In python I load the JSON using json.loads(r.text). The strings inside the data object are not guaranteed to be those but can be any number. What I want to be able to do is to be able to get those numbers so I can store then in an array. In this example I want the array to look like [123,212,343]. Is there anyway to do this since they are nested objects and not a JSON array?

Thanks

Comment: that's not valid JSON. Please show a complete example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very briefly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json

foo = json.loads('{"123": null, "234": null, "456": null}')
print map(int, foo.keys())
```

The list `foo.keys()` will not be in the same order as presented in the JSON object (or its string representation).

If you need to preserve ordering, you might try the following modification:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json, collections

foo = json.loads('{"123": null, "234": null, "456": null}', object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
print map(int, foo.keys())
```

As you iterate over the list of keys, you can do a reverse lookup on an individual key in the usual way.

Note that you will likely want to convert the integer-key back to a Python string with `str()`, in order to retrieve its associated value. If you just want the list of keys for lookups, however, and you don't really need the actual integer values, you can skip the initial `map` call and just preserve the keys as strings.